# How to mount Btrfs with "errors=remount-ro" equivalent?

Tags: mount, fstab, btrfs

Btrfs does not appear to support errors=remount-ro. In /etc/fstab, what option can I use with Btrfs to achieve equivalent result as "errors=remount-ro"?

Comment: Btrfs appears to already mount read-only upon encountering errors. The only place where I found relevant information is [here](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Project_ideas#Forced_readonly_mounts_on_errors).

Comment: @yjwong looks good to me and seems to be the only source. You should post that as an answer, so that this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Btrfs wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Project_ideas#Forced_readonly_mounts_on_errors), it seems that Btrfs already appears to mount as read-only upon encountering errors. Hence, the flag `errors=remount-ro` is not required.